# PDO 'undefined index' Notice

Tags: php

I have a list of news and I have also a form to search for news.

So I created a session that stores an SQL command that I want to run if the search form is submitted, and so far it works well.

The problem is when the form is not submitted, my SQL command has the `{$_SESSION[where]}` in the SQL statement and then I'm having an error **undefined index 'where'**.

So, the problem I'm having is that when I'm not passing any value to my `$search` then the SQL command needs the value of `$search` and then because I did not pass this value I've got the error saying that no such variable is defined.

I've been trying various alternatives for hours but I didn't find any good solutions, can you please give me a little help?

I have a form with the name `sendForm`, then I have this code when the user submits the form:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
    {
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Search...')
        {
            $_SESSION['where'] = "AND titulo LIKE '%$search%'";
            header('Location: index2.php?exe=posts/news');          
        }
        //clean search
        else
        {
            unset($_SESSION['where']);
            header('Location: index2.php?exe=posts/news');
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Then I have my read statment for the articles but also for the search results:

```
$pag = (empty($_GET['pag']) ? '1' : $_GET['pag']);
$max = 15; 
$begin = ($pag * $max) - $max;
$readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from news {$_SESSION[where]}  ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT ?, ?");   
$readNews->bindValue(1, $begin,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readNews->bindValue(2, $max,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readNews->execute();
```

Comment: `session_start();` isn't loaded. Plus, what's this `SELECT * from news {$_SESSION[where]}`?

Comment: Change `{$_SESSION[where]}` to `{$_SESSION['where']}` and as @Fred-ii- stated above ^

Comment: Your query reads as `("SELECT * from news AND titulo LIKE '%$search% ORDER BY...` you probably meant to use a comma, if `news` and `titulo` are two columns. It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks dbh, but the problen still continues!

Comment: News is the table, title is a column of the news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly; If the user/you does not supply a **`$search`** query, you unset the session variable -> **`$_SESSION['where']`** with this if block:

```
if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Search...')
        {
            $_SESSION['where'] = "AND titulo LIKE '%$search%'";
            header('Location: index2.php?exe=posts/news');          
        }
        //clean search
        else
        {
            unset($_SESSION['where']);
            header('Location: index2.php?exe=posts/news');
        }
```

What you ***aren't*** doing though is checking if the session variable is set when you get to your PDO statements. Evident when looking at your snippet:

```
$pag = (empty($_GET['pag']) ? '1' : $_GET['pag']);
$max = 15; 
$begin = ($pag * $max) - $max;
$readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from news {$_SESSION[where]}  ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT ?, ?");   
$readNews->bindValue(1, $begin,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readNews->bindValue(2, $max,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readNews->execute();
```

**Assuming** that you **do** check for `session_start()` before this, you will need to add in a check to see that **`$_SESSION['where']`** is set.

Something like this should suffice:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['where']) && !empty($_SESSION['where'])) {
    // Do PDO query stuff
} else {
    // No $search query supplied.....do something else.
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in that way I will need to do 2 read sql statments right? One statement when the $_SESSION['where'] exists and other when this session dont exist right?

Comment: The first query will be if the user supplied the search terms and the second query will be a `"fail safe"` for you that you fall back to. That could be a redirect to an error page or a query that displays all the searchable content. That is entirely up to you :)

Comment: Let me know how that goes and if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
```

to

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['sendForm']) && isset($_POST['search']))
```

Comment: In the second part, the one which starts with $pag, did you start the session?

Comment: I start session for a login system in other page that includes this one!