# Invalid parameter number error

Tags: php, pdo

Im having an invalid parameter error but I guess that I have the right number of parameter.

Does anyone see the opposite here?

**Im getting this error:**

PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in $readNews->execute();

```
 if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, ?");  
    $readNews->bindValue(1, $search);
    $readNews->bindValue(1, $begin,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $readNews->bindValue(2, $max,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    else
    {
    $readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, ?"); 
    $readNews->bindValue(1, $begin,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $readNews->bindValue(2, $max,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }

    $readNews->execute();
```

Comment: Don't use `AND` use a comma `SELECT * FROM news, title LIKE`

Comment: But the title is not a table, the title is a column I want to select * from news where title like $search!

Comment: You probably meant to use `WHERE` as Phil posted below. I saw [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22851219/) earlier which kind of boggled my mind about it. I knew I was right about something.

Comment: Yes..Many hours in front of pc and its that (lol)

Comment: But Im having the same issue with the updated statement!

Comment: I know the feeling ;-) Ask Phil; he knows his PDO quite well; better than me, *that's for sure*.

Comment: You also had an extra `"` in `LIMIT ?, ?"");` for both your queries by the way. Notice SO's syntax highlighting?

Comment: Scratch my last comment; Phil fixed your code in your question. Just don't repeat the same mistake ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three parameters yet you assign a value to index `1` twice. Try this...

```
$readNews->bindValue(1, $search);
$readNews->bindValue(2, $begin,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readNews->bindValue(3, $max,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I'm guessing you may want to wrap some wildcard characters around the `$search` value too. Try this...

```
$readNews->bindValue(1, "%$search%");
```

... or use `CONCAT` in your query...

```
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

Your query should also use `WHERE` instead of `AND`...

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, ?"
```

I would probably simplify this by using named placeholders to remove some of the duplication. In total, this...

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT :begin, :max");
    $stmt->bindParam(':search', $_POST['search']);
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM news  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT :begin, :max');
}
$stmt->bindParam(':begin', $begin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':max', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: By the way, do you think this method is a nice solution? Because it seems a bit amateur for me, because of the code repetition. But I was here with a problem for hours, and now  now I think about this solution and it works, but again, I dont know if it is a correct method..

Comment: Thanks your pretty solution works fine :) I just needed to update your second select statement for this $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT :begin, :max");

Comment: @John23 The quotes around that query string should not make a difference

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was something else that I had bad!